# Not able to round the picture corners in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

So I have worked on an Image with an Overlay in multiple ways and today tried this clean approach in the morning

In this one, I cannot do 'rounded' corners

https://play.tailwindcss.com/exkzRLth9L

Answer (score 10):

I should have rounded and also used **overflow-hidden**, which I did not.

So the role of

```
overflow-hidden
```

is important to ensure that container box is rounded else internal items won't let is look rounded

```
<div class="relative mx-auto rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
```

on line 4 of my sample made it work

Answer (score 1):

To make the corner rounded , add `rounded:2xl` or `rounded:xl` or `rounded:md` or `rounded:lg` as per the size of the radius of corners you want to the div containing the card

Here  sizes are in order `2xl>xl>lg>md`.

Comment: This answer is wrong!
Correct way to set the radius of the corner is to use a "-" instead of ":".
E.g. rounded-xl, rounded-2xl and so on.
See here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-radius

The ":" you used in your comment is used in tailwind for breakpoints: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design