# Rounding of div with tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I tried to round my div, on PC screen and site its good, but on mobile i have a outlined square?
site deployed with netlify
checked this question: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1949
[Not able to round the picture corners in Tailwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327591/not-able-to-round-the-picture-corners-in-tailwind)

that doesnt worked for me

```
<div class="w-[45%] md:pl-5 hidden sm:block  ">
  <!-- MY PHOTO -->
  <img
    class="w-48 h-48git 2xl:m-auto rounded-full outline-2 outline-purple-500 outline overflow-hidden"
    src="/components/myphoto.png"
    alt="My Photo"
    style="border-radius: 50%;"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce in Tailwind Play? I tried https://play.tailwindcss.com/6T8Y4fIOrj and it seems to be rounded in both desktop and mobile.

Comment: its look good even in an browser phone simulation, but after deploying, i have this weird thing 
deploy:

https://oleksandr-shtefan.netlify.app/

Comment: Your photo looks circular on Chrome on Android. Maybe you're using iOS, and this is a Safari issue?

Comment: On iphone 12& iphone 7 its squared, iphone 14 & iphone 13 - rounded, idk why, both in safari or chrome

Comment: Likely different versions of iOS and thus different versions of the Safari engine.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/border-radius), `border-radius` has issues when applied to images on Safari 6.1 and earlier. See [Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17202128), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17210864/7797661). It looks like you should be able to fix the problem by applying border-radius to the wrapping div you already have:

```html
<div class="w-[45%] md:pl-5 hidden sm:block rounded-full" style="border-radius: 50%;">
  <!-- MY PHOTO -->
  <img
    class="w-48 h-48git 2xl:m-auto rounded-full outline-2 outline-purple-500 outline overflow-hidden"
    src="/components/myphoto.png"
    alt="My Photo"
    style="border-radius: 50%;"
  />
</div>
```

Note that Chrome on iOS uses Safari as a rendering engine, so it has the same behavior.

Comment: that doesnt help:( but thanks for your time